# Tell gcc/g++ compiler remove orphaned functions

Tags: c++, c, c++11, gcc, compiler-optimization

There are some functions which are never called. Not because they are not called under some logic but because they are never called from tree of main function. assuming:

```
int A()
{
   if(...)
      call F();
}

int B()
{
}

int C()
{
    call B();
}

int D()
{
    call A();
}

int F()
{
    call A();
}

int main()
{
    call D();
    call F();
}
```

so in this example:

```
main  ---> D
       |
       --> F

D  ------> A
F -------> A
A -------> F
C -------> B
```

So in no way by running this application B and C have chance of being called. They are orphan. But it seems gcc/g++ do not remove orphan functions as I have checked:

program 1:

```
int main()
{
    int a=4;
    int b=3;
    int c=a+b;
    b=c-a;
    a=c-b;
    return 0;
}
```

running in command line:

```
g++ -std=c++11 test.cpp
md5sum a.out
```

I get:

```
546da269abddb8dcb3883527a362f769  a.out
```

Now by adding an orpan function (test), I get different executive file:

program 2:

```
int test()
{

}

int main()
{
    int a=4;
    int b=3;
    int c=a+b;
    b=c-a;
    a=c-b;
    return 0;
}
```

running in command line:

```
g++ -std=c++11 test.cpp
md5sum a.out
```

gives different hash:

```
64095263965d2d94ed2f305f99a2b25a  a.out
```

It shows that this orphan function which will never be called in my program has influenced the compiled code.
Is there any way to tell gcc/g++ to remove orphan functions?

Comment: Merely recompiling the *exact* same source file will give a different hash too. GCC is not designed to always give the bit-for-bit same output file when you pass the same input file. Can you edit your question to include a more reliable test?

Comment: A function is never considered "orphaned" because its symbol is exported and available to other compilation units, which is something that gcc can't detect.

Comment: So, is there any source code level tool providing such facility to export my codes (excluding standard header files) to minimal code?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the point of this.  Wouldn't it be better to just clean up your code by yourself?

Comment: @OmnipotentEntity what if our application is a final executive which is never used by any other application?

Comment: @nchen24 imagine there is a pile of codes and you cannot do it by yourself as you write code incrementally during a long time. so, in real situation finding orphaned functions is not such easy and simple.

Comment: @barej You can always use some terminal-fu like `nm ./a.out | c++filt | grep ' T ' | cut -f 3- -d' '` to get a list of the functions shown in the debug symbols, and grep for occurrences of those functions.

Answer (score 1):

When compiling use optimization option. The `-O` flag that is passed to the compiler

**Change**

```
g++ -std=c++11 test.cpp
```

**TO**

```
g++ -O1 -std=c++11 test.cpp
```

with this option the `md5sum` for both the program will be the same.

**Program 1:**

```
int main()
{
    int a=4;
    int b=3;
    int c=a+b;
    b=c-a;
    a=c-b;
    return 0;
}
```

and **Program 2:**

```
int test()
{

}

int main()
{
    int a=4;
    int b=3;
    int c=a+b;
    b=c-a;
    a=c-b;
    return 0;
}
```